# select box loading depending on choices made

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

My problem is the following:

I have two select boxes. In the second, the option that is loaded depends on which option i chose in the first.

Here's my result:

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#durata').change(function() {
        var durata = $("#durata").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "elaborazione_dati.php",
            data: "durata=" + durata,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#prezzi").html(msg); 
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        });
    });     
});

    <form>
            <p>durata</p>
            <select name="durata" id="durata">
                <option>Scegli...</option>

                <?php 

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM acquisti";
                $q = $db->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute();

                $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                while($row = $q->fetch()) {  

                ?>
                <option><?php echo $row['durata']; ?></option>

            <?php } ?>

            </select>

            <br />

           <p>prezzi</p>
            <select name="prezzi" id="prezzi">
            <option>Scegli...</option>
            </select>
    </form>

include("elaborazione_dati.php");
```

elaborazione_dati.php

```
echo $_POST['durata'];

$durata = $_POST['durata'];

    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM acquisti WHERE durata = ".$durata."");
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

foreach ($result as $value) {

    echo "<option value=".$value['idacquisti'].">".$value['prezzi']."</option>";    

}
```

The main problem is that the "durata" variable is considered an Undefined index and i can't load correctly the options of the second select.

Can you give me some tips?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try `data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`

Comment: Or even 
`data {'durata' : $('#durata').val()}`